# How can I create a Rust development environment on Windows ARM64?

Tags: windows, rust

I want to create a Rust development environment on Windows ARM64(without WSL).

Official packages are available and appear to be usable.
(https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html)
But, this package require Microsoft VisualStudio toolchain. It does not seem to be able to be installed on Windows ARM64.
How can I create a Rust development environment on Windows ARM64?

Answer (score 1):

Windows usually does not come with the Microsoft Visual Studio toolchain installed. However, the rust installer for windows is usually able to install it for you. If you need to install it manually, you can go to https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/. Since you only need the build tools, just download the community edition and then in the installer you can select the specific MSVC packages you want. Alternatively, I believe selecting the C++ option in workloads will also add the necessary packages.

According to the list of [supported platforms](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/rustc/platform-support.html), the target for ARM64 with Windows is `aarch64-pc-windows-msvc`. I do not see any other ARM64 targets listed other than the MSVC version so if you want to use Rust on Windows, it looks like using MSVC is your only option.

The general purpose windows installer should work, but if you want to make sure you are installing a specific target you can instead download the msi you want in the [Standalone Installers](https://forge.rust-lang.org/infra/other-installation-methods.html#standalone-installers) list.

When I installed Rust on my x86_64 laptop with the general windows installer it offered to install MSVC for me so I imagine that the standalone installer for `aarch64-pc-windows-msvc` should be able to do the same.

If the official installer for your system does not work for some unforeseen reason, you can raise an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup).

Comment: Full MSVC edition isn't required. Installing only the build tools package is enough, and much much smaller. on the isntaller page, drill down to **Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022**